# REST return empty but HTTP_OK in java application

Tags: java, rest

Generally speaking, how does one begin to solve a problem when the exact URL/headers used in a java web application, contacting a commercial endpoint using HttpURLConnection, returns nothing but a status of OK.

But, when using Postman, those values bring back the expected results perfectly fine.

The headers;

Identical URLs
"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
"Accept", "application/json"
"Authorization", "Basic foOo0bAAaaAar"

I'm just looking for a place to start, or things I've missed, so more of a general pointer would be amazing.

Comment: I'd start logging the request and the response in your app, and comparing with the one intercepted from postman.

Comment: Your responses  can always lie when you set them explicitly the wrong status, which is not

Answer (score 0):

Your rest api can return with http 200 with empty body, like this:

```
@GET
@Path("...")
public Response doSomething() {
    ...
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Or with body:

```
@GET
@Path("...")
public Response doSomething() {
    ...
    return Response.ok().entity("say something").build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be more thorough about how you parse strings. That's how. argh, sorry for wasting the time.